# Open hidden window with JavaScript and show it later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ASP.Net website, I would like to load 2 pages at the same time. The main page should load the second page. I want to make the second page hidden until the user call it. I want to do this because the second page is doing some calculations first. I tried this

```
<script>
    var mypage=window.open('page.aspx','_blank','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', ''); 
    mypage.blur();
</script>
```

But this did nothing, and the second page is still visible.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to open invisible windows.

Comment: Maybe I can open it behind the main window and minimized until the user call it.

Comment: Try blurring the new window to make it pop under...then focus it when ready

Comment: I don't think Javascript is able to minimize and maximize windows.

Comment: I used mypage.blur(); but it is still one the front.

Comment: Try `window.focus()` on the original window.

Comment: Or use an `iframe`, then when the user wants it, open a new window with `"data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML)` as the URL. If your page has too much HTML, that might not work, depending on the browser.